# Symfony2 - Doctrine DQL - many to many query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, many-to-many, dql

I have entities `Offer` and `Area` and here one `Offer` can have many `Areas` and one `Area` belong to many `Offers`:

`Offer` entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Area")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="relationship_offer_areas",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="area_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $areas;
```

Now I am trying to get `Offers` by `Area` using DQL (not query builder!):

```
$query = 'SELECT o FROM IndexBundle:Offer o '.
    'LEFT JOIN IndexBundle:Area a '.
    'WHERE a = :area '.
    'ORDER BY o.startDate ASC';
```

Here `:area` is `Area` entity object. Unfortunately it is not working as expected. I get all offer rows with all the areas.

Any ideas what am I missing? Working with Entities in query language really twist my mind. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT o FROM IndexBundle:Offer o '.
'LEFT JOIN o.areas a '.
'WHERE a.id = :areaId '.
'ORDER BY o.startDate ASC';
```

It doesn't know how to use the `JOIN` on the fly. Use the properties of your entities for joining. It's is just like you do a `LEFT JOIN` within SQL as you refer to a column where you want additional data from. As you specify in the `ON` of the join.

> Left join using DQL - See documentation: [Doctrine DQL - Select examples](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-select-examples)
>
> ```
> $query = $em->createQuery('SELECT u.id, a.id as article_id FROM CmsUser u LEFT JOIN u.articles a');
> $results = $query->getResult(); // array of user ids and every article_id for each user
> ```